# How do you reference only the persisted records in an active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the edit method of many controllers you initialize a new object and edit existing objects

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:magazine_id])
      @page = Page.find(params[:id])
      @new_page = @magazine.pages.new
   end
end
```

However in a view you will often want to cycle through the persisted objects and treat the new object separately

```
# magazines#edit
%h4 Existing pages
- @magazine.pages.each do |page|
  %p= link_to page, page.title
```

### The problem

...is that the `pages` association contains both existing (persisted) pages but also the new page which we made via `@new_page = @magazine.pages.new`.

It's easy to deal with this however it's ugly

```
%h4 Existing pages
- @magazine.pages.each do |page|
  - if page.persisted?
    %p= link_to page, page.title
```

I would like to use some assocition method to select only those pages which are persisted:

```
%h4 Existing pages
- @magazine.pages.persisted.each do |page|
  %p= link_to page, page.title
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Did you tried `@magazine.pages.select(&:persisted?)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the suggestions from @Florent2 and @CDub are sound. However @florent2's suggestion meant hitting the database again (and potentially ditching any preset eager loading which I didn't want to do) and @CDub's suggestion didn't quite work out in terms of code. Here is what I ended up going with:

### Returning only persisted records for a particular association

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages do 
    def persisted
      collect{ |page| page if page.persisted? }
    end
  end
end
```

this allows you to call `.persisted` on any ActiveRecord relation of pages associated with Magazine. It doesn't hit the database again as it simply filters through the pre-loaded objects returning the ones which are persisted.

### Making the code reusable

Since I want to reuse this code on a regular basis I can pull it out into a module

```
module PersistedExtension
  def persisted
    select{|item| item if item.persisted?}
  end
end
```

It can then be included into the association methods using a lambda:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :pages, -> { extending PersistedExtension }

end
```

and I can call it intuitively:

```
@magazine = Magazine.first

@magazine.pages.persisted
# => array of pages which are persisted

# the new persisted association extension works on any AR result set
@magazine.pages.order('page ASC').persisted
```

Comment: I needed to compact the array because I was getting nil returned. `collect{ |page| page if page.persisted? }.compact`

Comment: @dazonic `select(&:persisted?)` returns the same result and looks much cleaner. See [documentation for `Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

Answer (score 17):

You can create in your Page model a `persisted` scope: `scope :persisted, -> { where.not(id: nil) }`, which avoids iterating on each associated page to check whether it's a new record or not.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too Florent. My only concern with this as a long term approach is that it hits the db which doesn't seem necessary given that the records are already in an array in memory. However, I'm wondering if the right approach might be to create a `.persisted` method on the model and then do a mapping `def persisted pages.collect{|page| page if page.persisted?}`. What do you think? The downside of course is that it ceases to be an AR relation, the nice thing is that it's fast. (I've missed our code convos btw ;)

Comment: Ahh, I see that my suggestion was exactly what @CDub suggested!

Comment: Don't know exactly how is your view, but in case in `%h4 Existing pages` it's the first time you iterate on pages, it's fine. At this moment the pages are not in memory yet, `@magazine.pages` is just an ActiveRelation object which is lazy loaded, so adding `.persisted` will change just the SQL query executed to fetch the record (by adding an extra condition on the `id`), not generate an extra SQL request (I miss our code convos too :) ).

Comment: Good point - I forgot about lazy loading. Which route do you prefer out of interest - filtering the array or changing the query?

Comment: If I face the issue only in a single view, I would probably just put `- next if page.new_record?` after `- @magazine.pages.each do |page|`, (I admit that's ugly :) ) else would go with the `persisted` scope. Too bad that Rails inject the new record in the array :S EDIT: seems that you can use the native `scoped` instead of the custom `persisted`to achieve the same result (but the semantic is not straightforward).

Comment: I forgot about the `.new_record?` query, that makes sense. I'm really not sure why Rails combines both new and old records into the same array. It's somewhat useful in a form where you both edit and create but could equally be done using two separate arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You could always reject pages that are new records...

```
%h4 Existing pages
- @magazine.pages.persisted.each do |page|
    %p= link_to page, page.title
```

where on `Page` you'd have something like:

```
def self.persisted
  reject {|page| page.new_record? }
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking about. The downside is that it ceases to be an AR relation, the upside is that if the data's already in memory it doesn't bother hitting up the DB again.

Answer (score 2):

I approach this problem differently. I do not create a new object in the controller, but instead do so directly in the form.

First, to run through your controller, why are you passing the page_id as your primary `params[:id]` to your Magazines controller? Looks to me that you want this:

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:id]).includes(:pages)
   end
end
```

Then, in your `magazines#edit` view, you'd do this:

```
%h4 Existing pages
- @magazine.pages.each do |page|
  %p= link_to page, page.title

= form_for @magazine do |f|
  = f.fields_for :pages, @magazine.pages.build do |builder|
    = builder.text_field :title
    # etc.
```

In that `fields_for` line, you're asking for magazine-form fields for pages, but then telling it to only render the fields for a specific, new page, which you are creating on the fly with `@magazine.pages.build`.

References:
[fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)
[Nested Model Form Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) (See also Part 2)

Comment: Hi Carlos. This is definitely a reasonable approach however I always prefer to instantiate objects in the controller than in the view. I can never remember whether there are consequences in this case but in general it feels cleaner. BTW I actually use cancan to `load_and_authorize_resource` - I put the object loading stuff in there just to illustrate (p.s. I enjoyed your goals blogpost)

Comment: Also you only push the problem downstream here. Once you've instantiated the new object it will still affect anything else which references the `.pages` association. The only difference is that it's only view code downstream of it which will be affected

Comment: Hmm, you are right about pushing the problem downstream. Having an implementation dependent on order of elements in the view is bad. That said, I don't like having a single controller action responsible for multiple instances variables on multiple classes. Such, in my code, is usually a sign that I'm approaching a problem incorrectly.

Comment: Is there any chance you could use a javascript-action, via an in-form link, to instantiate new fields for a page object? That way, the Ruby isn't responsible at all for creating a new object, and `@magazine.pages` never gets polluted. See `link_to_add_fields` here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: I could probably do something like that but unless there's a good reason not to, I always prefer to solve problems without JS before stepping things up. I feel that using JS in this instance will only muddy the waters - it's a generic problem

Answer (score 2):

## Rails 4 and 5 answer:

Just put this code in initializer (file in `config/initializers` directory, with `.rb` extension):

```
module MyApp
  module ActiveRecordExtensions
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    class_methods do

      def persisted
        select(&:persisted?)
      end

    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
  include MyApp::ActiveRecordExtensions
end
```

You can now call `persisted` on any model and association.

Comment: You should not be accessing `ActiveRecord::Base` directly, and instead use load hooks: `ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record { include MyApp::ActiveRecordExtensions }`

Comment: Yep, it's a good idea to not force `ActiveRecord::Base` to load too early. [Here is a blog post](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/04/understanding-ruby-and-rails-lazy-load-hooks) explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

Another cleaner syntax, using ActiveRecord `where.not` and still get back an `ActiveRecord` collection:

```
- @magazine.pages.where.not(id: nil).each do |page|
    ...
```