# SyntaxError on has_many association with block when trying to order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

in Ruby on Rails 4, let's say a parent has many children. Then I wanted to [reference only the persisted records in an active record association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842765/how-do-you-reference-only-the-persisted-records-in-an-active-record-association), and followed the link's accepted answer. This works good:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy do
    def persisted
      collect { |a| a if a.persisted? }
    end
  end
```

Now, I want to order the associated records:

```
has_many :children, dependent: :destroy, -> { order 'id asc' } do
```

but this raises an error:

SyntaxError in ParentsController#index

...trunk/app/models/parent.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting => ...trunk/app/models/parent.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

However, this does work:

```
has_many :children, -> { order 'id asc' } do
```

I can't even find documentation on how to use the do_block on an association. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was 2 problems with my approach:

1. The order of the arguments. In rails 4, the scope goes before the options.
2. The options hash should be wrapped, because it isn't the last argument anymore.

So, this code does work:

```
has_many :children, -> { order 'id asc' }, { dependent: :destroy } do
  def persisted
    collect { |a| a if a.persisted? }
  end
end
```

References:

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/5436931

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#461-User-a-block-to-extend-your-associations