# Rails: c.id submits nil in comment.each do |c.id| block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, associations

I'm trying to implement a comment system for users in which each comment can be upvoted. I have a model UpVote which polymorphically belongs_to multiple models, including Comments, while each User has_many Comments.

UpVote Model:

```
class UpVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :up_votes, as: :voteable
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :up_votes, as: :voteable
end
```

User Show: I put asterisks around the line with the error.

```
<% @user.comments.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.text %>
  <%= c.username %>
  <%= c.id %>
  ***<%= link_to "upvote", upvote_comment_path(c.id), method: :post, :class => "btn btn-small" %>***
<% end %>
```

Comment Controller:

```
def upvote
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  UpVote.create!(voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: 'Comment')
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Routes:

```
post 'comments/:id/upvote' => 'comments#upvote', as: 'upvote_comment'
```

But when I submit the UpVote for the Comment on the User page, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Users#show
No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

It seems like the link_to isn't accepting the `c.id`, which is strange because `c.id` on its own prints the @comment.id normally. What am I doing wrong?

ERROR IN BOUNTY MESSAGE: I meant "@comment.id", not "@comment.up_vote.count" in the bounty message, but it doesn't appear I can edit that.

Comment: Please show the route defined for this action in your `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: @spickermann I posted it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have a comment in the `@user.comments` that has an `id` of `nil` because it has not yet been persisted. This can happen if you are setting up a new comment on with either `@user.comments.new` or `@user.comments.build`. Both of these methods will add the blank comment to the `@user.comments` array.

There are a number of ways you can avoid displaying comments that are not persisted ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842765/how-do-you-reference-only-the-persisted-records-in-an-active-record-association)). I think the best solution is to avoid using `build` or `new` on the association. Instead if you need to display a new comment (such as in a form) prefer `Comment.new` over `@user.comments.build` or `@user.comments.new`.

Comment: I don't think that can be it, because I tested <%= c.id %> for a user with two comments; the first printed "1" and the other printed "3".

Comment: If you have a comment that has all nil values it won't show up because ``<%= nil %>`` displays nothing. A good way to check for this is to see what ``@user.comments.length`` is.

Comment: Wow you're right, it returns 3. What do you reccommend I do? Do I have to wipe the database?

Comment: No the problem is that you have a comment in ``@user.comments`` that has not been saved to the database (which is why it's ``id`` is ``nil``). See my updated answer for how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Well the correct way to solve the problem is to modify the `routes.rb`, changing action `upvote` to be `on: :member`

```
  resources :comments do
    post :upvote, on: :member
  end
```

OR

```
post 'comments/:id/upvote' => 'comments#upvote', as: 'upvote_comment'
```

Comment: I tried both ways; for the first way, I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'on' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0xb220f8c0>` and for the second I get the same error I posted in my question.

Comment: I've updated the answer, with the right convention for the route. the `:id` must appear before the action.

Comment: Hmm, now the route seems to work, but I'm once again getting the original error, even though I'm using `(id: c.id)`.

Comment: I have tested it with `upvote_comment_path(c.id)` and its working. can you double check that your controller is called 'Comments' (pluralized) ?

Comment: Yes, it's called Comments. That's pretty strange that it works for you but not for me.

Comment: I know this does't seem logical, but can u change the path to `upvote_comment_path(1)`, i need to make sure that the id is passed correctly.

Comment: for some reason the `c.id` is `nil` in the `upvote_comment_path(c.id)` path

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because <%= c.id %> prints "1" when I remove the link_to line.

Answer (score 0):

What may be happening is that you have created a static rather than a resourceful route. In this case you may have to actually specify the id explicitly in your link_to

```
<%= link_to "upvote", upvote_comment_path(:id => c.id), method: :post, :class => "btn btn-small" %>
```

You can avoid this extra markup by creating a resourceful route as in you attempted in your example

```
resources :comments do
 member do
   post 'upvote'
 end
end
```

Not sure why the "on: :member" syntax didn't work for you though as it is functionally equivalent to the block syntax. I believe the issue may be that you are specifying the action (upvote) with a symbol instead of string.

Good luck