# Listing a model and providing a form in the same page -- how to keep that new object out of the list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've got a pretty simple rails app with a form that shows all outstanding `Invite`s, and then a form to add a new Invite (that uses `@relation.invites.build`).

The problem is that in listing all those existing `Invite`s, a final one is shown with no data -- the `new` Invite for the form.

E.g. `Invite.all` includes `[{id: 1, email: bill@example.com}, {id: 2, email: pat@example.com}, {id: nil, email: nil}]`.

I could make a simple `:persisted` scope to filter out the new one, but this seems like a smell and I'm wondering if a pattern or convention exists to deal with this little issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Edited.

My previous example did not actually work as I had expected.
calling `.build` on a relation actually modifies the value stored in memory as it is by reference.

Instead you can use `Invite.new(relation: @relation)`.

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_relation, only: [:index]

  def index
    @invites = @relation.invites
    @new_invite = Invite.new(relation: @relation)
  end

  def set_relation
    @relation = Relation.joins(:invites).find(params[:relation_id])
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe InvitesController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #index" do

    let!(:relation) { create(:relation) }
    let!(:invite) { create(:invite, relation: relation) }

    before { get :index, relation_id: relation }
    it "does not include the new invite in @invites" do
      expect(assigns(:invites)).to eq [invite]
    end

    it "assigns a new invite as @new_invite" do
      expect(assigns(:new_invite)).to be_a_new Invite
    end

    it "assigns the correct relation to the new invite" do
      expect(assigns(:new_invite).relation).to eq relation
    end
  end
end
```

---

Another alternative is to cast the association collection to an array:

```
def index
  @invites = @relation.invites.to_a # is not by reference
  @new_invite = @relation.invites.build
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `select(&:persited?)`. This will select only persisted records for the invites excluding the initialized one. You dont need to make a scope,when it is already there.

```
@relation.invites.select(&:persisted?)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It seems wasteful to always have to enumerate over a collection, though -- and a scope to do this would at least save from having an n+1 processing every pageload.

Comment: if you are building the invites in the controller for @relation, then `select(&:persisted?)` will pick the the invites from the cache. secondly. scope also has query in it. i don't know how are you pointing this to be n+1 queries. try this in rails console and you will not see any query on this `select(&:persisted?)`

Comment: Scope will build the select statement and pull in one go, using `select(&:persisted)` will iterate over the collection, which is n+1 time (not n+1 queries).

Comment: i cant say much as data is already in memory so iterating over it is not an issue. but it is definitely your call. and the answer above is as good as one could be..:) i read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842765/how-do-you-reference-only-the-persisted-records-in-an-active-record-association might be helpful to you too.:)