# Can't access non-persisted associations in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5.1

**Problem:** I have two models called `Contract` and `Appendix`. The latter has the scope `persisted` for excluding non-persisted objects. I'd like to write spec for the scope but seems I can't access non-persisted associations inside specs at all.

**Models:**

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appendixes
end

class Appendix < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
  scope :persisted, -> { where 'id IS NOT NULL' }
end
```

**Appendix model spec:**

```
context 'within persisted scope' do
  it 'returns only persisted appendixes' do
    contract = Contract.create(attributes_for(:contract))
    Appendix.create(attributes_for(:appendix, contract: contract))
    contract.appendixes.new
    byebug
  end
end
```

**Examples:**

When byebug breakpoint is reached then `contract.appendixes` returns the same as `contract.appendixes.persisted` despite the fact that before byebug, new non-persisted appendix is initialized and that should make a difference (?):

```
(byebug) contract.appendixes
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
(byebug) contract.appendixes.persisted
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

Meanwhile when repeating the same spec in rails console, it works as expected:

```
2.5.1 :061 > c = Contract.last
2.5.1 :062 > c.appendixes
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
2.5.1 :063 > c.appendixes.new
 => #<Appendix id: nil, ...
2.5.1 :064 > c.appendixes
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Appendix id: nil, ...
2.5.1 :065 > c.appendixes.persisted
  Appendix Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "appendixes".* FROM "appendixes" WHERE "appendixes"."contract_id" = $1 AND (id IS NOT NULL) LIMIT $2  [["contract_id", "b3a1645b-d4b1-4f80-9c43-6ddf3f3b7aba"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

I use [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) attributes for initializing objects directly to DB just in case (I previously initialized the object through FactoryBot completely but then I thought that FactoryBot might not interact with DB the usual way, this is also said in FactoryBot's [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/wiki/How-factory_bot-interacts-with-ActiveRecord)).

**Question:** How could I read the non-persisted appendixes from contract-object inside my specs?

**I use:**

- Ruby 2.5.1p57
- Rails 5.1.6
- RSpec 3.8.0
- FactoryBot 4.11.0
- FactoryBotRails 4.11.0

Comment: I found the scope from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19845632/1677069

Comment: Indeed it does look like it should have worked

Comment: Your console test does something slightly different. It calls `contact.appendixes` first (which likely puts them in the cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I might had `.reload` called on `contract` object in spec accidentally while testing. Because of that I guess the **cache** part that @Sergio and @ayushi pointed out actually played the role in this, thanks for mentioning!

I managed to write the spec with the help of FactoryBot too so no need to exclude it form this type of situation:

```
context 'withing persisted scope' do
  it 'returns only persisted appendixes' do
    contract = create(:contract)
    appendix = contract.appendixes.new
    expect(contract.appendixes).to include(appendix)
    expect(contract.appendixes.persisted).not_to include(appendix)
  end
end
```